# Store local database on the cloud

Tags: android

I want to develop a client/server system.
I already have the client part finished.
I have a local database on android using SQLiteDatabase that looks like this:

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // create tables

    String CREATE_MEASUREMENTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_MEASUREMENTS + "("
            + KEY_MEASUREMENT_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
            + KEY_FINGERPRINT + " INTEGER,"
            + KEY_BSSID + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_LEVEL + " INTEGER" + ")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_MEASUREMENTS_TABLE);  

    String CREATE_FINGERPRINT_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_FINGERPRINTS + "("
            + KEY_FINGERPRINT_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
            + KEY_MAP_NAME + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_POSITION_X + " FLOAT,"
            + KEY_POSITION_Y + " FLOAT" + ")";

    db.execSQL(CREATE_FINGERPRINT_TABLE);  
}
```

I want to be able to store this on the cloud, the users be able to retrieve the database and add,remove or update entries on the online database and be updated on other systems.

The system is just a proof of concept so it doesn't have to be very robust.

any recommendations on how to do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, how about using the public folder provided by http://www.dropbox.com/ ?

Here is a simple description of how it works : https://www.dropbox.com/help/20/en

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. the system is running on the background. so the database needs to be retrieved/updated automatically, the user doesn't have to retrieve the database manually (as in the case of Dropbox)

Comment: The file can be retrieved automatically like any other file from any other server.

After you get the file, the system can open it and use it as you see fit.

I've added a link with an explanation.

Comment: The idea is that the user can updated the database online. and other useres retrieve that updated database. is that possible with the method that you mention? thanks.

Comment: Emm, I don't think so.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the best way would be to use a MySql database on a server and access it via PHP.

This works really well for me at a Raspberry Pi at home.

See this Tutorial:

[Link to a Tutorial about Mysql and Android on Androidhive](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm looking for a faster way to implement it. maybe using a cloud-based service that can set up everything for me, I just need directions on the best way to implement this.